# Change Chrome Settings via Powershell

Tags: windows, google-chrome, powershell

I want to make a script to change the default page zoom in Chrome, however I do not know where these options are stored.
I guess that I have to find an appropriate options text file, parse it, and then make a textual replacement there, using powershell in order to apply the changes.
I need to do it every time I plugin my laptop to an external monitor, and it is kinda annowying to do it by hand

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default zoom level is stored in a huge JSON config file called `Preferences`, that can be found in the local appdata folder:

```
$LocalAppData = [Environment]::GetFolderPath( [Environment+SpecialFolder]::LocalApplicationData )
$ChromeDefaults = Join-Path $LocalAppData "Google\Chrome\User Data\default"
$ChromePrefFile = Join-Path $ChromeDefaults "Preferences"
$Settings = Get-Content $ChromePrefFile | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The default Page Zoom level is stored under the `partition` object, although it seems to store it as a unique identifier with some sort of ratio value, this is what it looks like with 100% zoom:

```
PS C:\> $Settings.partition.default_zoom_level | Format-List

2166136261 : 0.0
```

Other than that, I have no idea. I don't expect this to be a good idea, Chrome seems to update a number of binary values everytime the default files are updated, you might end up with a corrupt `Preferences` file

Comment: That was it. I just have to change the value in the JSON file, and when chrome restarts will have the new zoom level (even a non predefined: eg 126%)
Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$Env:
```

Is a special PSdrive that contains many of the SpecialFolder Paths

```
$Env:LOCALAPPDATA
```

and

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath( [Environment+SpecialFolder]::LocalApplicationData )
```

Yield the same result in addition to the rest of Mathias answer.