# Modify Chrome window position settings (in "preferences" file) using Powershell

Tags: windows, google-chrome, powershell

We have a kiosk with two screens, one for interaction with users and the second one just for some promo content. I need to ensure that Chrome will always open on the second screen on specific webpage on start-up. It runs on Windows machine...

I was looking for ways of first opening Chrome with Task Scheduler and than moving the window to second screen. But after some research and testing I ended up with opening Chrome in "kiosk mode" (useful thing btw) using provided URL using Powershell script. Thankfully, if I close Chrome window on second screen, it will remember the position and next time Chrome window opens, it will be placed "where I left it". However, I would like to ensure that even if some error will occur, Chrome "preferences" file (in AppData folder) will always set the position to my second screen.

I ran into ([Change Chrome Settings via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482405/change-chrome-settings-via-powershell)), but I am still unable to write working piece of code to modify this file on start-up (before opening Chrome window).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are unable to write a working one what have you got so far that we can help you with?

Comment: Why not just backup the settings file and then restore it?

Comment: This was is exactly my thinking (there are few reasons why I think it would be better solution in this case), so I gave up on my previous solutions. @Matt: I was able to replace contents of the file, but have no idea how to replace the whole file. It sounds so simple "take file and replace it with this one", but I did not find the answer anywhere here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I was tasked with getting Chrome to auto-open .ica files.

I wrote the below script to do just that:

```
get-childitem -path "$env:systemdrive\Users" | foreach-object {

  $path = "$env:systemdrive\Users\$_\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default\preferences"

  if(test-path $path){
    $prefs = get-content $path | convertfrom-json 
    if($prefs){

      if(!($prefs.download.extensions_to_open)){
        $prefs.download | add-member -name "extensions_to_open" -value "ica" -MemberType NoteProperty #-Force
      } else {
        if(!($prefs.download.extensions_to_open -match "ica")){
          write-host "No ICA"
          $prefs.download.extensions_to_open = $prefs.download.extensions_to_open + ":ica"
        } else {
          write-host "ICA file type will already auto-open, ignoring."
        }
      }
      $prefs | convertto-json -depth 100 | out-file $path -encoding utf8
    }
  }

}
```

You should be able to refactor this. It writes everything to the preferences file for each user on the machine and works well.

To save you some time, I've refactored the script for you:

```
get-childitem -path "$env:systemdrive\Users" | foreach-object {

  $path = "$env:systemdrive\Users\$_\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default\preferences"

  if(test-path $path){
    $prefs = get-content $path | convertfrom-json 
    if($prefs){

        $prefs.browser.window_placement.left = 500 # pixel value 
        $prefs.browser.window_placement.top = 100 # pixel value 
        $prefs.browser.window_placement.bottom = 100 # pixel value 
        $prefs.browser.window_placement.right = 100 # pixel value 
        $prefs.browser.window_placement.maximized = $false # $true or $false

      $prefs | convertto-json -depth 100 | out-file $path -encoding utf8
    }
  }

}
```

Happy scripting!

Answer (score 0):

Dan's answer was really helpful in writing to the preferences file. I did notice that if you don't specify the encoding from get-content it will increase the preferences file size every time you run it. Change the line below:

```
$prefs = get-content $path -encoding utf8| convertfrom-json
```