# How to change default download folder in Chrome using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, powershell-2.0

I am following this post - [Change Chrome Settings via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482405/change-chrome-settings-via-powershell)

So far I can get the download settings using `$settings.download.default_directory` but not sure how to set a different value. I have tried using `Set-Content` and `Set-ItemProperty` but no luck (former is giving access denied error when trying to execute this command:

```
Set-Content -Path $Settings.download.default_directory -Value 'C:\Users' -Force)
```

FYI I don't want to use Windows Registry to change the settings.

Comment: If you dont have Chrome running it seems you could just do something like `$Settings.download.defaultdirectory = "C:\path\to\new\location"` No?

Comment: Thanks. It allows me to change even if Chrome is running but downloaded file still goes to default folder(i think Chrome need to be restarted). Is there way that changes can be made on run time just like it can be changed from browser preferences?

Comment: E.g. `$Settings.download.default_directory = 'D:\Downloads'` and then save the value of string `ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $Settings -Depth 12 -Compress` back to the path `$ChromePrefFile`. IMHO you can't do it on the fly and Chrome should be off. BTW, in my _Google Chrome 70.0.3538.110_, download folder is saved  as `$Settings.savefile.default_directory` property.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome must be closed when doing this

```
$UserFolder = "$env:HOMEDRIVE" + "$env:HOMEPATH"
#ChromeSettingsFile
$File = "$UserFolder\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"
$Chrome = Get-Content $File | ConvertFrom-Json
$Chrome.download.default_directory = "$UserFolder\Downloads"
$Chrome | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath $File -Force
```

Comment: please use a multiline codebox for the code ^^ ... just looks cleaner